# Setup react-scripts globally

Tags: react-scripts

Is installing react-scripts on every project is necessary if you just want to setup new project as a playground? How to use react-scripts command when it's installed -g (globally) ? can it be simlinked ? What I am basically looking for is a project which only contains 
`"dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
    }`

and still be able to `npm start`

Answer (score 2):

The `react-scripts` is a dependency of `create-react-app` and doesn't have to be installed globally. This command is also not intended to be used globally or individually as it will be automatically installed for each project that uses `create-react-app` when you run `npm install`. If you need to create a new React app, you can see the documentation here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Comment: so I can't symlink or some workaround to avoid this huge package?

Comment: Well, it's not a CLI so I don't see what you would like to do with it as a command?

Comment: what I've tried is "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start', but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install every single time starting a new project in react. You can install react-scripts globally. Open .bin folder in your global node_modules file.
Find
`react-scripts`  `react-scripts.cmd` files and copy those.

> create a .bin folder in your current project directory and paste those two files.Also copy react-scripts folder from global node_modules and paste in current.
> This will solve the issue.
> you can use react-scripts globally.
> But you need to check for the react-scripts updates manually and upgrade it.

Comment: If this is not good. You can simply try parcel. install parcel globally and use it instead of react-scripts. That works really well.